# A question about higher dimentional triangles

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a proof about the triangle inequality in one of my textbooks and I am not understanding one of the steps. It's the following:

Let $P=(x_{1},...,x_{m}) \in R^{m}$, $Q=(y_{1},...,y_{m}) \in R^{m}$ and $R=(z_{1},...,z_{m}) \in R^{m}$.

To prove the triangle inequality $d(P,Q)\leq d(P,R)+d(Q,R)$ we need to show that

$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{2}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i}^{m}|y_{i}-z_{i}|^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i}^{m}|z_i-x_i|^2}$

The proof goes on to say that **given** that $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{2}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}(|y_i-z_i|+|z_i-x_i|)^2}$ it's sufficient to show that

$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}(|y_i-z_i|+|z_i-x_i|)^2}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i}^{m}|y_{i}-z_{i}|^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i}^{m}|z_i-x_i|^2}$

My question is twofold however:

1. How is that a given and is there some way to show this?
2. Is there some other way to prove said inequality, say the Euclidean Geometric proof?

Comment: For 1: Starting from  $|x_{i}-y_{i}|=|(x_{i}-z_{i})+(z_{i}-y_{i})|\leq |x_{i}-z_{i}|+|z_{i}-y_{i}|$ (which is the standard triangle inequality for real numbers) we can, since the absolute value has the range of the non-negative real numbers, square both sides and still preserves the "$\leq$". Then sum both sides over all $i$ and take the square root of both sides (both these actions will preserve the"$\leq$") and you are done.

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what i couldn't figure out!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you had in mind for 2 and in particular what you have at your disposal? For instance, using [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) the proof is practically done.

Comment: The description of the first question is sufficient. Some scripture online showed a less vector-oriented type approach with a traditional triangle supposedly achieving the same result and I was wondering if that might work as well. The link is here:

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01317.pdf

Comment: More precisely the chapter 1.1 and the proof with the triangle BCP.